# What will be the set of non-Wieferich numbers if the set of non-Wieferich primes is finite?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problems, integer-sequences

Integer $n$ is Wieferich number if $2^{\phi(n)}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {n^2}$.

Wieferich prime is Wieferich number with $n$ prime.

It is an open problem if there are infinitely many Wieferich primes
and infinitely many non-Wieferich primes.

In OEIS [Wieferich numbers are A077816](https://oeis.org/A077816).

Comment in OEIS claims:

> If there are finitely many Wieferich primes (A001220), this sequence is finite.

Let WP denote Wieferich prime and NWN denote non-Wieferich number.

It is unconditionally known that there are infinitely many non-Wieferich numbers with unbounded largest prime factor.

From now on **assume there are only finitely many non-Wieferich primes**
and almost all primes are WP.

Let $p_i$ be distinct WPs. Then $n=\prod p_i$ is Wieferich number
at it is not NWN.

> Q1 Are there only finitely many squarefree NWNs?

> Q2 What other properties NWNs have?

A guess:

> Q3 Must the smallest prime factor of the NWNs be bounded?

**Addedd** Initially we asked about the largest prime factor, but Will Sawin
disproved this and Q1 in a comment.

Comment: If $p$ is not a Wieferich prime, then any product of $p$ with primes not congruent to $1$ mod $p$ is not a Wieferich number. So the answers to Q1 and Q3 are negative.

Comment: @WillSawin Many thanks, you are right. I edited Q3, asking about the **smallest** prime factor.

Comment: Prime powers of any prime will eventually be NWN's, so I think the answer as stated to Q3 is still negative. If you mean squarefree then I think this is true: A product of distinct Wieferich primes is a Wieferich number, so the smallest prime factor of a squarefree non-Wieferich number must be at most the largest non-Wieferich prime.

Comment: @WillSawin I am trying to exploit the fact that Mersenne numbers $M_n$ are NWNs, but the squarefree part is obstacle. Maybe the fixed Q3 will be elementary result about $M_n$ being squarefree.